# Refer to an image from scss file on an app using vite_rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vite

I have a rails app that uses `vite_rails` for assets management.
In my `assets/images` directory, I have `my_image.png`
How can I refer to the image from my `application.css.scss` file?
I have tried

```
background-image: url('images/my_image.png');
background-image: url('my_image.png');
```

And a couple of more but none is working.

Comment: background-image: url('/assets/images/my_image.png');

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try `background-image:('/images/my_image.png')`.

Vite will serve it on the fly from `app/assets/images/my_image.png` in development and test environment. In production it will precompile it and serve it like `/vite/images/my_image.e3f3ce98.png`.

Also make sure you have `"sourceCodeDir": "app/assets"` set in `config/vite.json`